# List of Controls available in a Sharpoint 2010 WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part

I'm looking to create a part of a HTML page as a WebPart (not Visual WebPart) in Sharepoint 2010, and I'd like to understand the classes available within the WebPart to create HTML components.

Currently, I know of a few:

`Panel` - creates a `<div>`

`Button` - creates a `<button>`

`Label` - creates a `<label>`

`DropDownList` - creates a `<select>` (dropdown)

`ListBox` - creates a `<select size='...'>` (listbox)

`TextBox` - creates a `<input type='text'/>`

`LinkButton` - creates a `<a href=...>`

Could you provide a full list of controls available in WebPart? (For example, how do I create a `<span>`?)

**Update:**
This is mostly what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx, though this list doesn't directly mention which HTML component results from adding the control to the page.

Comment: This is a broad question, and to me more related to ASP.net than it is to SharePoint per se. I think you should ask this question on StackExchange instead.

Answer (score 1):

In a Sharepoint WebPart you can create any ASP.NET control as you have shown above!

If for example you want a direct HTML control to be added to the page than you would need to do this:

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='htmlDiv'>"));
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='http://www.google.com'>this is a html link</a>"));
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
```

**EDIT**
As it is so broad in the amount of controls you could test the results!

Within the CreateChildControls() do:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "tb";
tb.Text = "test";
this.Controls.Add(tb);
```

The above would add a TextBox to the page! Go into the browser and hit F12 to get developer tools running and inspect the HTML generated!

I suspect that it would be an `<input>` tag generated ;) for TextBox and most other controls like button, label etc!

Comment: Thanks! I will use this approach to create the `<span>` I wanted. Check my update to the question, and please post if you know which controls directly translate into which HTML components.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: Many thanks! I shall try this, and publish the full list of the controls vs. HTML components here if I can.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the client (browser) is considered, SharePoint page (and WebPart as the part of the page) is just normal HTML document and therefore every HTML tag is valid tag in any SP page (and WebPart).

Comment: You've probably misunderstood my question. I'm looking for the names of ASP.NET classes that translate directly into HTML tags on a page. For example, `Panel` creates a `<div>`, when added to the page using `this.Controls.Add(new Panel());` So what class creates a `<span>`? What creates a `<h1>`? And so on.